# How can i retrieve data from the database with the url slug which is arabic

Tags: sql, codeigniter, url, unicode, arabic

[image]

my url is passed liked that and i am trying to retrieve information based on the slug in that url but all i get is this %D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%AF-%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87-%D9%8A%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%89-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%87-%D8%A3%D9%88-%D9%8A%D8%A8%D8%AA%D8%BA%D9%8A%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%85-UdPlIFtwewFW

And i cant use that to for my Mysql query to get information from the database. Please help i am trying to make a multilingual app in codeigniter but that ARABIC issue has been a problem, how can i go about it

Comment: [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use urldecode to retrieve the original arabic text from encoded string:

```
<?php
$text = 'الغديات والعشيات" لن تنفع!';

echo rawurlencode($text);

$encoded_text = "%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA%22%20%D9%84%D9%86%20%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B9%21";

echo "\n";
echo urldecode($encoded_text);
?>
```